# Hadoop:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/slaves: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop

I followed the steps on the hadoop offical site exactly as it says, but it always shows the following error:

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/videni/Tools/hadoop-1.0.3/libexec/../logs/hadoop-videni-namenode-videni-Latitude-E6400.out
cat: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/slaves: No such file or directory
cat: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/masters: No such file or directory
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/videni/Tools/hadoop-1.0.3/libexec/../logs/hadoop-videni-jobtracker-videni-Latitude-E6400.out
cat: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/slaves: No such file or directory
```

Right now, i just want to set a Standalone Operation, should I have to set the three xml files, such as core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml?
I checked the log files, some of them say `Error: JAVA_HOME is not set`, but I set it in the hadoop-env.sh file.

Comment: Are you saying you haven't put anything into those three xml files? Even for standalone operation you need to configure those files.

Comment: yep, i put them later,but it is still the same

Comment: What steps did you take to start your cluster? Did you use `start-all.sh`?

Comment: 1) i  downloaded the official recommended jre, it is jre1.7.0_06 in my situation, and the stable version hadoop-1.0.3,2)i unzipped them into a same directory ,for example,videni, then i set JAVA_HOME=JRE_HOME in hadoop-env.sh. JRE_HOME is the directory i just unzipped to plus jre1.7.0_06，that is /videni/jre1.7.0_06.3)install ssh,and  rsync ,after that , i executed the code below:ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.4)Format current distributed-filesystem: hadoop namenode -format.5)start up the hadoop daemons:start-all.sh.

Comment: i installed them 3 times,it is still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files depends on $HADOOP_HOME path. Make sure that you have $HADOOP_HOME set up properly in ~/.bashrc.